# Removing Custom Serialisation for JSON objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I currently have a custom serialiser. Purpose of my custom serialiser is to format my JSON object from this: `{"id":["21","22", 23"]}` to this `{"id":"21,22,23"}`.

My current implementation of my custom serialiser:

```
public static class ListSerialiser implements JsonSerializer<List<Member>> {

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(List<Member> src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            List<String> memberId = new ArrayList<>(src.size());
            for (Member member : src) {
                memberId.add("" + Member.getId());
            }
            String memberIdAsString = TextUtils.join(",", memberId);
            object.addProperty("[%s]", memberIdAsString);

            return object;
        }
    }
```

Although my implementation got me what I wanted, just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there's a way to serialise without having to use Text Utils or string formatters to achieve this outcome: `{"id":"21,22,23"}`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to join strings, you can see most of them [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strings-concatenation)

My favourite is:

```
String memberIdAsString = memberId.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```